# Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Schrödinger operator. Why is $u(x,t)\xrightarrow{t\to\pm\infty} 0\iff\sigma_p(\mathcal{H})=\emptyset$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $\mathcal{H}:=V-\Delta$ be the Schrödinger operator, $V\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ and let $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a solution of the equation

$$\left(\Delta-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u(x,t)=V(x)u(x,t)\qquad(1)$$

How does it follow that $u(x,t)\xrightarrow{t\to\pm\infty} 0\iff\sigma_p(\mathcal{H})=\emptyset$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where $\sigma_p$ is the point spectrum?

Note that this is a result from [Professor Tao's blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/israel-gelfand/#more-2860)

I have thought a little bit about the "$\Longleftarrow$" direction:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{H}u=\lambda u
\\
\iff&(V-\Delta)u=\lambda u
\\
\iff&(\Delta+\lambda)u=V u\qquad(2)
\end{aligned}$$

This is equivalent to $(1)$ if $\lambda=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$. However, that doesn't make sense.

$\sigma_p(\mathcal{H})=\emptyset$ implies that $\nexists$ $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $(2)$

Comment: So what you want to prove is that  $u(x,t) \to 0$ for every solution of the Schrödinger equation if and only if the point spectrum is empty, right?

Comment: @user159517 Well, Professor Tao's statement is that $u(x,t)\to 0$ as $|t|\to\infty$ *if and only if* the point spectrum is empty. However, it is correct that the first step in proving this is to show that $u(x,t)\to 0$ as $t\to\pm\infty$ *implies* that the point spectrum is empty; thus I would indeed like to know how one proves that.

Comment: well, he says "any reasonable u", whatever that is supposed to mean. Also, he confines himself to the one-dimensional case

Comment: @user159517 The setting of my question is also $\mathbb{R}$ and he states that an example of a "reasonable" $u$ is "finite energy". Note that "finite energy" is terminology used in electrical engineering and refers to "square integrable".